# View all pending promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, timeout

In my tests, sometimes I get timeouts, and it would be very useful to see what where the promises that were pending before the timeout, so that I know what promises have the most chances of being in an "always pending state".

Is there a way to do that ?

Here's an example code :

```
Promise.resolve().then(function firstFunction() {
    console.log(1);
    return 1;
}).then(function () {
    return new Promise(function secondFunction(resolve, reject) {
        // NEVER RESOLVING PROMISE
        console.log(2);
    });
}).then(function thirdFunction() {
    // function that will never be called
    console.log(3);
})

setTimeout(function timeoutTest() {
    const pendingPromises = [];// ??????????? how do I get the pendingPromises
    console.log(pendingPromises);
    process.exit();
}, 5000);
```

I would like, if possible, to get in `pendingPromises` the name of the function and stacktrace of the promise `secondFunction`, since it is the one that will never resolve.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Monitoring pending async operations in Node.js promised environment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38781512/1048572)?

Comment: Wow.. you are terribly confused... There is no way to return the synchronous timeline once you get into the promises (AKA asynchronous timeline).

Comment: They could be some features around it, it just is like à timeline and all links are explicit. It could be possible to wrap promises so that you get this sort if information.

Comment: For example https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector/pull/76

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A promise chain is designed progressively to deliver values down its success path or a "reason" down its error path. It is not designed to be enquired at some arbitrary point in time for a "snapshot" the state of individual promises that are assimilated by it.

Therefore, a promise chain offers no "natural" way to do what you ask.

You need to contrive a mechanism for :

- registering promises of interest.
- tracking each registered promise's state (if not already provided by the promise implementation).
- retreiving, on demand, the registered promises, filtered by state.

A constructor along these lines will do the job :

```
function Inspector() {
    var arr = [];
    this.add = function(p, label) {
        p.label = label || '';
        if(!p.state) {
            p.state = 'pending';
            p.then(
                function(val) { p.state = 'resolved'; },
                function(e) { p.state = 'rejected'; }
            );
        }
        arr.push(p);
        return p;
    };
    this.getPending  = function() {
        return arr.filter(function(p) { return p.state === 'pending'; });
    };
    this.getSettled = function() {
        return arr.filter(function(p) { return p.state !== 'pending'; });
    };
    this.getResolved = function() {
        return arr.filter(function(p) { return p.state === 'resolved'; });
    };
    this.getRejected = function() {
        return arr.filter(function(p) { return p.state === 'rejected'; });
    };
    this.getAll  = function() {
        return arr.slice(0); // return a copy of arr, not arr itself.
    };
};
```

*The only methods required by the question are `.add()` and `.getPending()`. The others are provided for completeness.*

You can now write :

```
var inspector = new Inspector();

Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    console.log(1);
}).then(function() {
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // NEVER RESOLVING PROMISE
        console.log(2);
    });
    return inspector.add(p, '2');
}).then(function() {
    // function that will never be called
    console.log(3);
});

setTimeout(function() {
    const pendingPromises = inspector.getPending();
    console.log(pendingPromises);
    process.exit();
}, 5000);
```

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLzL4p0o/)**

The use of `Inspector` isn't confined to promises assimilated by promise chains. It could be used for any arbitrary set of promises, for example a set to be aggregated with `Promise.all()` :

```
promise_1 = ...;
promise_2 = ...;
promise_3 = ...;

var inspector = new Inspector();
inspector.add(promise_1, 'promise 1');
inspector.add(promise_2, 'promise 2');
inspector.add(promise_3, 'promise 3');

var start = Date.now();
var intervalRef = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(Date.now() - start + ': ' + inspector.getSettled().length + ' of ' + inspector.getAll().length + ' promises have settled');
}, 50);

Promise.all(inspector.getAll()).then(successHandler).catch(errorHandler).finally(function() {
    clearInterval(intervalRef);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think that is the best solution. A real project could even be made starting from this idea, to for example have a way to review all promises :-). Anyway, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using library such as [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/) that is ~6x times faster than native promises, offers useful warnings and additional useful methods like - timeout which might help you with this issue.