# How can I track the number of unfulfilled promises in a NodeJS application?

Tags: node.js, settimeout, es6-promise

I frequently use a pattern in NodeJS & JavaScript where I combine a timeout with another promise using Promise.race, like this...

```
let timer
let p1 = x => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bSomeFunctionCall(x) ? resolve() : reject()
  }).finally(() => { console.log('p1 done') })
}
let p2 = ms => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      reject('timeout')
    }, ms)
  }).finally(() => { console.log('timeout done') })
}
let p3 = Promise.race([p1(v1), p2(3000)])
await p3.finally(() => {
  console.log('race done')
  clearTimeout(timer)
  console.log('done')
})
```

EDIT: Typo, 'timer' is a variable in scope for clearing.

However, I never see the p2.finally() message unless it times out & rejects, which makes me wonder if every time I use this pattern I create an unfulfilled promise floating around out there... potentially thousands of them.

I'm wondering if clearTimeout() in p3 causes the promise to resolve and since resolve() isn't defined, it just quietly settles, but shouldn't I see p2's finally() call?

**I don't understand how p2 can settle and not call it's finally() method.**

How can I debug this to convince myself I'm not making a mess under the hood? I was hoping there's a way to examine the number of outstanding promises in a debug mode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.finally(() => { console.log('timeout done') })` always gets called, unless you never `reject` that `Promise`, which happens because you're clearing the timeout apparently when `Promise.race` is settled.

In your code you assign the timeout id to `timer` but then issue `clearTimeout` with `timeout` variable, which isn't defined in that script. So I'm assuming you're clearing the `p2` promise timeout, and since `p1` finishes first, when you clear the timer `p2` never gets settled.

So don't use `clearTimeout` since doesn't make sense if you're using `Promise.race`, and `finally` will always be called on `p2`

---

**Just for debugging purposes**, you can override `Promise` constructor to keep track of all promises.

```
Promise = class extends Promise {
    static list = []
    constructor(...args) {
        let p = super(...args)
        Promise.list.push(p)
        return p;
    }
};

// Promise.list (will contain all promises, filter by `pending`
```

You can also check this answer: [View all pending promises in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273680/view-all-pending-promises-in-javascript)

Comment: 1. That was a typo, timer is defined outside the code and is used for clearTimeout(). 2. I absolutely need to clear the timeout because my code sets an error flag on reject, and if you don't clear it, the flag is ALWAYS set. I had to simplify the code for the example. 3. If I never reject the promise, does the promise settle or is it floating around out there? I'll try the inspector. Thanks.

Comment: If you clear the timeout, then the promise never settles. You're not doing anything on reject since the Promise race already resolved, so you don't need to clear the timeout, at least not in the code you posted. And if you're talking about a different code, then we can't help you since that code is not in the question.

Comment: "If you clear the timeout, then the promise never settles." Thanks, that was my actual question. And thanks for the constructor override idea.