# Best way to calling API inside for loop using Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have 500 millions of object in which each has n number of contacts as like below

```
var groupsArray = [
                    {'G1': ['C1','C2','C3'....]},
                    {'G2': ['D1','D2','D3'....]}
                     ...
                    {'G2000': ['D2001','D2002','D2003'....]}
                     ...
                ]
```

I have two way of implementation in nodejs which is based on regular promises and another one using bluebird as shown below

Regular promises

```
...
var groupsArray = [
                    {'G1': ['C1','C2','C3']},
                    {'G2': ['D1','D2','D3']}
                ]

function ajax(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request.get(url,{json: true}, function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(data);  
            }
        });
    });
}
_.each(groupsArray,function(groupData){
    _.each(groupData,function(contactlists,groupIndex){
        // console.log(groupIndex)
        _.each(contactlists,function(contactData){
            ajax('http://localhost:3001/api/getcontactdata/'+groupIndex+'/'+contactData).then(function(result) {
                console.log(result.body);
              // Code depending on result
            }).catch(function() {
              // An error occurred
            });
        })
    })
})
...
```

Using bluebird way i have used concurrency to check how to control the queue of promises

```
...
_.each(groupsArray,function(groupData){
    _.each(groupData,function(contactlists,groupIndex){
        var contacts = [];
        // console.log(groupIndex)
        _.each(contactlists,function(contactData){
            contacts.push({
                contact_name: 'Contact ' + contactData
            });
        })
        groups.push({
            task_name: 'Group ' + groupIndex,
            contacts: contacts
        });
    })
})

Promise.each(groups, group => 
    Promise.map(group.contacts,
         contact => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                /*setTimeout(() => 
                    resolve(group.task_name + ' ' + contact.contact_name), 1000);*/
                request.get('http://localhost:3001/api/getcontactdata/'+group.task_name+'/'+contact.contact_name,{json: true}, function(error, data) {
                    if (error) {
                        reject(error);
                    } else {
                        resolve(data);  
                    }
                });
}).then(log => console.log(log.body)), 
{
    concurrency: 50
}).then(() => console.log())).then(() => {
    console.log('All Done!!');
});
...
```

I want to know when dealing with 100 millions of api call inside loop using promises. please advise the best way to call API asynchronously and deal the response later.

Comment: Which version of Node?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I am using 6.10.0

Comment: Can you use 7.7?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yeah :)

Comment: You're missing _some_ parallelism, the last 4 calls in a group in the above code only execute at once without a fifth because the group is done, you might perform better in the above case if you `flatMap` the groups' contacts and then use `{concurrency: 5}` on that (though 5 is really low if you have 5 million records)

Comment: Maybe something like https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/efacac6c643dd3c6f268e37c0668db21 ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Now changed concurrency to 50...

Comment: I would probably still not pass the data on http. I'd have one server write it to a database and the other reading it directly from there with a querying language. Keeping millions of records in an array is almost never a good idea.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum core idea is to store each 10/more group into redis jobmanager and later start worker for it. so finally redis start call that 10 group with that n number of contact.:)

Answer (score 5):

My answer using regular Node.js promises (this can probably easily be adapted to Bluebird or another library).

You could fire off all Promises at once using `Promise.all`:

```
var groupsArray = [
                    {'G1': ['C1','C2','C3']},
                    {'G2': ['D1','D2','D3']}
                ];


function ajax(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request.get(url,{json: true}, function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(data);  
            }
        });
    });
}

Promise.all(groupsArray.map(group => ajax("your-url-here")))
    .then(results => {
        // Code that depends on all results.
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Handle the error.
    });
```

Using `Promise.all` attempts to run all your requests in parallel. This probably won't work well when you have 500 million requests to make all being attempted at the same time!

A more effective way to do it is to use the JavaScript `reduce` function to sequence your requests one after the other:

```
// ... Setup as before ...

const results = [];

groupsArray.reduce((prevPromise, group) => {
            return prevPromise.then(() => {
                return ajax("your-url-here")
                    .then(result => {
                        // Process a single result if necessary.
                        results.push(result); // Collect your results.
                    });
            });
        },
        Promise.resolve() // Seed promise.
    );
    .then(() => {
        // Code that depends on all results.
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Handle the error.
    });
```

This example chains together the promises so that the next one only starts once the previous one completes.

Unfortunately the sequencing approach will be very slow because it has to wait until each request has completed before starting a new one. Whilst each request is in progress (it takes time to make an API request) your CPU is sitting idle whereas it could be working on another request!

A more efficient, but complicated approach to this problem is to use a combination of the above approaches. You should batch your requests so that the requests in each batch (of say 10) are executed in parallel and then the batches are sequenced one after the other.

It's tricky to implement this yourself - although it's a great learning exercise 
- using a combination of `Promise.all` and the `reduce` function, but I'd suggest using the library [`async-await-parallel`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-await-parallel). There's a bunch of such libraries, but I use this one and it works well and it easily does the job you want.

You can install the library like this:

```
npm install --save async-await-parallel
```

Here's how you would use it:

```
const parallel = require("async-await-parallel");

// ... Setup as before ...

const batchSize = 10;

parallel(groupsArray.map(group => {
        return () => { // We need to return a 'thunk' function, so that the jobs can be started when they are need, rather than all at once.
            return ajax("your-url-here");               
        }
    }, batchSize)
    .then(() => {
        // Code that depends on all results.
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Handle the error.
    });
```

This is better, but it's still a clunky way to make such a large amount of requests! Maybe you need to up the ante and consider investing time in proper asynchronous job management.

I've been using [Kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) lately for managing a cluster of worker processes. Using Kue with the Node.js cluster library allows you to get proper parallelism happening on a multi-core PC and you can then easily extend it to muliple cloud-based VMs if you need even more grunt.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49353384/25868) for some Kue example code.

Comment: Appreciate your brief explanation. I had used Kue manager lately to implement it

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you have two problems coupled in one questions - I'd decouple them.

#### #1 Loading of a large dataset

Operation on such a large dataset (500m records) will surely cause some memory limit issues sooner or later - node.js runs in a single thread and that is limited to use approx 1.5GB of memory - after that your process will crash.

In order to avoid that you could be reading your data as a stream from a CSV - I'll use [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) as it'll help us with the second problem, but `JSONStream` or `papaparse` would do pretty well too:

```
$ npm install --save scramjet
```

Then let's read the data - I'd assume from a CSV:

```
const {StringStream} = require("scramjet");

const stream = require("fs")
    .createReadStream(pathToFile)
    .pipe(new StringStream('utf-8'))
    .csvParse()
```

Now we have a stream of objects that will return the data line by line, but only if we read it. Solved problem #1, now to "augment" the stream:

#### #2 Stream data asynchronous augmentation

No worries - that's just what you do - for every line of data you want to fetch some additional info (so augment) from some API, which by default is asynchronous.

That's where `scramjet` kicks in with just couple additional lines:

```
stream
    .flatMap(groupData => Object.entries(groupData))
    .flatMap(([groupIndex, contactList]) => contactList.map(contactData => ([contactData, groupIndex])
    // now you have a simple stream of entries for your call
    .map(([contactData, groupIndex]) => ajax('http://localhost:3001/api/getcontactdata/'+groupIndex+'/'+contactData))
    // and here you can print or do anything you like with your data stream
    .each(console.log)
```

After this you'd need to accumulate the data or output it to stream - there are numbers of options - for example: `.toJSONArray().pipe(fileStream)`.

Using [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) you are able to separate the process to multiple lines without much impact on performance. Using `setOptions({maxParallel: 32})` you can control concurrency and best of all, all this will run with a minimal memory footprint - much much faster than if you were to load the whole data into memory.

Let me know how if this is helpful - your question is quite complex so let me know if you run into any problems - I'll be happy to help. :)