# Track nodejs promise memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, promise, async-await

I'm debugging a memory leak in my node.js application that uses a lot of async functions (native async of node 8.x). In chrome inspector in "Record allocation timeline", I see that most of memory leaked are promises and objects retained by such promises.

So I suppose that I have some promises that never do finish. Is there any way to track such promises and reasons why they do not finish (for example, stack traces where they are stuck)? Or is there any other way to track promise-related memory leaks?

I see some similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781512/monitoring-pending-async-operations-in-node-js-promised-environment) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273680/view-all-pending-promises-in-javascript), but all the solutions listed seem to require substantial rewrite of all the code (mainly using a different promise library), which is quite difficult in my case, especially since I am using promises implicitly, via async/await.

I've found also node 8.x async hooks that look interesting, but this is not excatly what I need (tracks creating of resources, not places where promises are stuck), and also seems rather low-level.

If that's important, part of promises come from mongoose (with `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;`), and most of my code in written on Coffeescript.

Comment: Promises that never finish are not a GC problem per se. There must be something that is the actual source of the leak which keeps holding on them, *possibly* still resolving them. Check the memory snapshots for what things reference these promises.

Comment: Would it be possible for your case to set up some simple `setTimeout` functions to reject your promises after a certain time, so at least you can figure out which ones are stuck?

Comment: @Bergi do you mean that if promise is not held by any variable, it is destroyed and promise is not completed? But a simple `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Ok"); resolve(); }, 1000);});` prints `Ok` even if the promise object is not saved to any variable.

Comment: @Behrooz, as most of my promises are coming from async/await functions, I don't see any way to do this

Comment: @Petr The promise could also be held by a variable, but what matters is that it is held by the `resolve` function and whoever holds `resolve` - in your example, the global timeout. If you setup something like `setTimeout(resolve, Infinity)`, the promise is never resolved and still kept in memory, but the source of the leak is not the promise but the infinite timeout.

Comment: @Bergi, I see. Will try to understand who holds these promises.

Comment: @RobRaisch - Your characterization of promises as black magic is laughable.  They are simply a notification system, not really much different than a typical observer design pattern except that these are one shots only (can only be resolved or rejected once).  They can even be implemented in plain Javascript (see the Bluebird promise library for an example).  Absolutely no magic at all.  And, they are GCed exactly when any other object would be GCed, when no active, reachable code still has a reference to them.

Comment: Well, the very first thing to do is to examine heap snapshots and figure out which promises are not getting GCed.  Then, once you have some idea which ones they are, you can start examining your code to see who might be retaining a reference to them.  Resolved or not does not matter, only who still has a reference to them.  An unfinished asynchronous operation that still could finish in the future probably does retain a reference to the promise (so it can still resolve it), but presumably your code could be instrumented to determine which async operations never finish.

Comment: @RobRaisch - Promises call their `.then()` handlers asynchronously on the next tick of the event loop.  If you're trying to use promises for a synchronous operation, then duhhhh they're going to be slower because ever iteration is forced to wait for the next tick of the event loop.  If there's a real asynchronous operation behind each promise, then it simply does not matter than the notification occurs on the next tick of the event loop because any real asynchronous operation has to notify on the next tick of the event loop anyway.  That's how async callbacks work (even without promises).

Comment: @RobRaisch - So your bashing of promises here is really out of place.  Please stay on topic.  If the OP really has a promise memory leak, then this is a coding problem, not a problem with the way promises are designed and they would likely have a problem with any type of notification system because their code is hanging onto some sort of reference that it shouldn't be.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the clarification/education. I've excised my comments.